# Is there an English translation of Monique Hakim's thesis?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, topos-theory, paper-request, translation

Monique Hakim's thesis, published in 1972 as *Topos annelés et schémas relatifs*, has been referenced on a multitude of occasions. But I struggle to find a translation into English, even an informal one. Is there a translation into English anywhere?

Comment: if you are happy with an "informal" translation, just feed the thesis to DeepL.

Comment: Yes but that would require me to have it in a form that could be recognized and processed by DeepL...

Comment: @xuq01: Electronic version of the book is available (with OCRed text) here: https://annas-archive.org/md5/4402f05e2f09cdd417202bae001fcb53

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of what you can expect: Google gives free access to parts of the book, I OCR'ed the [first page of the introduction,](https://books.google.nl/books?id=F8qcDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=true) fed it to DeepL and got this back:

> The idea of the present work, to define a theory of relative diagrams
> above a ringed space, i.e. to give meaning to the notion of "relative
> diagrams", over a ring space, i.e. to give meaning to the intuitive
> notion of a family of schemes parametrized by an annulated
> space, is already suggested in A. Grothendieck's lectures at
> the Cartan 1960/61 lectures no. 7 to 17. The question raised
> then was the following question: do certain module problems of scheme
> theory still make sense when reformulated in the category of ring
> spaces into local rings over a given ring space, e.g. an analytic
> space an analytic space or a differentiable variety. The notion of
> relative should enable us to use the results of classical scheme
> theory as they stand to solve these problems, while taking into
> account their algebraic nature. Similarly, the notion of over  an
> analytic space (in the sense of [10] Lecture 9) should give rise  to > an interpretation of the results of H.Grauert and R. Remmert [9]
> concerning direct upper images of coherent beams by the canonical
> projection
>
> [formula]
>
> where X is an analytic space and X x P' is the analytic space product
> of X by the typical projective space of dimension r, by a theory of
> the GAGA type [19] over an analytic space.
>
> However, with a view to other applications, we prefer the framework of
> ringed topos to the overly restrictive framework of ringed spaces. In
> the first two chapters, we develop some essential prelimi- essential
> for using ringed topos. These form a 2-category, i.e., roughly
> speaking, the Hom of such objects themselves have a
> category structure. The need to to be able to apply descent methods in
> such a context leads us to the definition of a fibered 2-category and
> a 2-field on a site. The notion of 2-field is simply the adaptation to
> the case of 2-categories of the notion of field introduced by J.
> Giraud in his Thesis.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question "Is there a translation into English anywhere?" Rather, this should be a comment (without giving the DeepL output).

Comment: I find this a helpful answer demonstrating the extent to which DeepL does or doesn't provide an acceptable English translation.

Comment: @TomLeinster : Yet, is it an answer to the question "Is there a translation into English anywhere?"?

Comment: @TomLeinster An alternative would be to feed each page directly to Claude or GPT-4 as a PNG and ask for an English translation, e.g. [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPIZA.png) is translated as [this](https://pastebin.com/bzNrdqFG) by "Claude Sonnet", the second best (and completely free) Claude model.

Comment: (There are some wrong translations, though, such as "2-adjoint à droite" being translated as "2-adjoint to the right" instead of "right 2-adjoint".)